# Remove white space from the bottom of screen Android

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

How i can remove this white space at the bottom of the screen. I have also tried `android:adjustviewbounds` and `android:scaletype`. But still failed to remove the white space at the bottom of the screen. Please help me to optimize my layout so that i can remove that ugly white space from the bottom.

Here is the screenshot below of my layout screen.

[image: Screenshot of layout]

Here is my XML code of the layout.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.zohai.v360.Fragments.Home">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/intro"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@drawable/intro"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-15dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/photog"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/photographers"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="190dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-14dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/model"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/model_bg"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: It's the blank portion as there's still some height of screen left after 3x190 and why are you using negative margins...?

Comment: What I can understand from your question is that you have these three pics and you want it to occupy your entire screen leaving no white space. Is this what you want?

Comment: Yes that is what i exactly want

Comment: i was using negative margin to remove white space between the images

Comment: Simply use a background image like the one used in your ToolBar. By the way... why are you using all those **meaningless LinearLayouts**?! Remove them all, as soon as possible! Nesting layouts is **bad for performances**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your xml code you have mentioned

```
android:layout_height="190dp"
```

Which usually does not help in `android:scaletype`

Please your **constrain layout** or **linear layout with weight** to distribute 3 linear layout to the screen height. Like this,

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp">
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp">
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginTop="-15dp">
```

and then use `android:scaletype` to fit the `LinearLayout`

Note : Different screen size matters, I think in your case the screen height is high, which cause the layout to have blank space in bottom. In small size screen it may not be like that. Try doing above will help in all screen size

Answer (score 1):

Your layout's height is set to `wrap_content`. The whitespace is there because you don't have enough size of the content to fill the screen completely. If you set the height to `match_parent` you could make the whitespace go away by setting `android:background` on the root view.

Otherwise you have to find out what you want there. Changing the size of the images is a bad idea because they will look stretched.

And because android is a big platform, you will see that on some devices the whitespace won't be there and on others it will be bigger. Don't set the size of the images to a fixed size.

Comment: I'm using scroll view so the layout inside the scroll view cannot be set to android:height = "match_parent"

Comment: I have set the root layout (Relative layout) height to match parent but still white space is there

Comment: False. YOu can set the height of the ScrollView and the RelativeLayout to `match_parent`. It is the LinearLayout inside the ScrollView that needs to be `wrap_content`